# Constraints for Direct Collocation method in pydrake

Tags: drake

I am looking for a way to describe the constraints of the Direct Collocation method in pydrake.
I got the robot model from my own URDF by using `FindResource` as [this](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/c3422ad4b624290688ef9e00b87b940c91247a32/underactuated/cartpole/dircol_swingup.py)(l11-16).
Then, I tried to make some functions which calculate the positions of the joints as `swing_foot_height(q)` of [this](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/exercises/simple_legs/compass_gait_limit_cycle.ipynb).
However there is a problem.
It is maybe a type error.
I defined `q` as following

```
robot = MultibodyPlant(time_step=0.0)
scene_graph = SceneGraph()
robot.RegisterAsSourceForSceneGraph(scene_graph)
file_name = FindResource("models/robot.urdf")
Parser(robot).AddModelFromFile(file_name)
robot.Finalize()
context = robot.CreateDefaultContext()

dircol = DirectCollocation(
    robot,
    context,
    ...(Omission)...
    input_port_index=robot.get_actuation_input_port().get_index())

x = dircol.state()
nq = biped_robot.num_positions()
q = x[0:nq]
```

Then, I used this `q` for the function like `swing_foot_height(q)`.
The error is like

```
SetPositions(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
...
q: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[m, 1]]
...
Invoked with:
...
array([Variable('x(0)', Continuous), ... Variable('x(9)', Continuous)],dtype=object)
```

Are there some way to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right.  In the compass gait notebook that you cited, there was an important line:

```
# overwrite MultibodyPlant with its autodiff copy
compass_gait = compass_gait.ToAutoDiffXd()
```

so that multibody plant that was being used in the constraint is actually an AutoDiffXd version of the plant.

The [littledog notebook](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/e621d09eb436f27e13b9b77f68a1a2c9e0ce6050/examples/littledog.ipynb) has more examples of this, with a more robust implementation that works for both float and autodiff constraint evaluations.

Comment: I didn't understand the difference of the plant version. The littledog example is very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand this, trajectory optimization with `DirectCollocation` converts the data type of the decision variables (in your case, x and q) to `AutoDiffXd` type. That is the type you're seeing here in the "Invoked with" error message. This is the type used for automatic differentiation which is used for finding the gradients for the optimization solver.

You'll need to convert back to float to use the `SetPositions()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Indeed, it seems that I used the incorrect data type.